# How to implement multi-threaded import of numpy arrays stored on disk as dataset in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

The input and labels of my dataset is stored in 10000 `.npy` files each. For example `inputs/0000.npy,...inputs/9999.npy` and `labels/0000.npy,...labels/9999.npy`. While each file independently can be stored in memory, the whole dataset of 20k arrays cannot be stored in memory. I would like to implement multi-threaded CPU pipeline to import the dataset as batches of say `batch_size=8`.

I have tried to implement the functions mentioned in the new Tensorflow data API but haven't found any example for my requirements. All examples seem to be for cases where the whole dataset can be loaded into RAM. Any idea how to approach this?

Comment: If you consider my answer to correctly answer your question, I invite you to click on the checkmark at the left side of my answer to assign it as the correct answer and close this question.

Comment: Thank you. I was just making sure I understand everything correctly by implementing a concrete example of your code. This is exactly what I was looking for. Wish the Tensorflow API documentation wasn't so convoluted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use [`tf.data.Dataset.from_generator()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#from_generator) which allows you to use Tensorflow data API through a custom python generator function. This way, you can load each `.npy` file iteratively, having only one `numpy.ndarray` loaded in memory at once. Assuming that each loaded `numpy.ndarray` is a single instance, an example code for your case might be something as following:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import os


def gen():
    inputs_path = ""
    labels_path = ""
    for input_file, label_file in zip(os.listdir(inputs_path), os.listdir(labels_path)):
        x = np.load(os.path.join(inputs_path, input_file))
        y = np.load(os.path.join(labels_path, label_file))
        yield x, y


INPUT_SHAPE = []
LABEL_SHAPE = []

# Input pipeline
ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
    gen, (tf.float32, tf.int64), (tf.TensorShape(INPUT_SHAPE), tf.TensorShape(LABEL_SHAPE)))
ds = ds.batch(8)
ds_iter = ds.make_initializable_iterator()
inputs_batch, labels_batch = ds_iter.get_next()
```

I have not tested the code. Hope it helps!